# Are the epsilon numbers the ones greater than $\omega$ unreachable from below with exponentiation?

Tags: logic, ordinals

Let $\varepsilon$ be an epsilon number, i.e., an ordinal such that $\omega^{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon$. Is it true that then, for each pair $\alpha,\beta$ of ordinals, with $\alpha,\beta < \varepsilon$, we have $\alpha^\beta < \varepsilon$?

Does the converse also hold? If $\varepsilon$ is an infinite ordinal unreachable from below with exponentiation, is it an epsilon number?

I suspect this is the case (I haven't seen it written anywhere) but I'm having trouble to prove it. Ordinal exponentiation doesn't behave so nicely.

If there exist $\alpha, \beta < \varepsilon$ with $\alpha^\beta = \varepsilon$, we can show that the Cantor Normal Form of $\varepsilon$ has at least two terms, but I don't know what to do if we have $\alpha^\beta \geq \varepsilon$...

Comment: Well, if $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_{\eta+1}$ for certain $\eta$, then if $\alpha, \beta < \varepsilon$, then $\alpha < {\varepsilon_\eta}^{{{\varepsilon_\eta}^{...}}^{\varepsilon_\eta}}$ and we have something similar for $\beta$, so $\alpha^\beta < ({\varepsilon_\eta}^{{{\varepsilon_\eta}^{...}}^{\varepsilon_\eta}})^{({{\varepsilon_\eta}^{{{\varepsilon_\eta}^{...}}^{\varepsilon_\eta}}})}$. That maybe helps.

Comment: Also if we prove the converse by transfinite induction on $\rho$ where $\varepsilon = \varepsilon_\rho$ then the limit case becomes fairly easy.

Comment: Just because it's not obvious from the answer to the other question: It's Theorem 15.10 of Monk's Introduction to Set Theory.